# apt-get slows horribly inside a Docker

Tags: docker, performance, dockerfile, freeze, apt-get

I have noticed recently that either building Docker Image OR running in already built container, `apt-get update` & `apt-get install` slows down(almost as if it is hung) with below output:

```
 ---> Running in 04b74c43b24e
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [34.9 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [931 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [1655 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [2269 kB]
```

I confirm that on host, it is not the problem.

Searching web, some links pointed me to containers having many file-descriptors and they would keep increasing and eventually cause `apt-get` to slow down.

I tried running containers with `--ulimit nofile=:1024:2048`, but I still face the same problem.

Below is the docker version I am at:

```
╰─>$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.18
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.6
 Git commit:        b40c2f6
 Built:             Thu Sep  8 23:11:45 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.18
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.6
  Git commit:       e42327a
  Built:            Thu Sep  8 23:09:37 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.8
  GitCommit:        9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

I have tried, different systems available. I am behind proxy but confirm that proxies are set correctly.

Comment: How often are you running `apt-get`? Did you put the step where you copy your code into the container before or after the step where you run `apt-get`?